# Understanding the basics of :host-context

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm really lost with `:host-context`. :(

I watched a few videos, read the MDN page and tried to play around in VSCode to understand.

All I understood (maybe wrongly) from my tries was that with `:host-context` I can access a "DOM layer" between Shadow DOM and the regular, light DOM and style it.

Can someone explain `:host-context` to me like I'm 5 years old?

Comment: FYI, AFAIK Mozilla and Apple will **not** implement ``host-context``, So it is a Chromium only party. Search for ``:slotted`` for posts on styling shadow and light DOM

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes, I like the *idea* of web components and shadow DOM, but I won't use them in production and I've moved away from using them for my personal projects as well. Too much friction.

Comment: Yes, Google tried to force their ideas on the world for a long time with the V0 version. But since 2018, with V1 Web Components, there is better cooperation between Apple, Mozilla, Google and Microsoft. **V1 is solid**, alas many blogs out there still list V0 ideas... they should be burned down. Then you would never have found ``host-context``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that `:host-context` is like `:host` except you can pass it a selector, and it will *only match if the shadow host matches that selector in the light DOM*. So lets say you have a custom element my-element. You want to style this div background color: red, but *only* if the `my-element` is in an H1, because it shouldn't appear in an H1 and the red is a clear sign to the dev that they made a mistake.

You can do this:

```css
:host-context(h1) { background-color: red }
```

And the red background will *only* show up if my-element is a descendent of an h1.

```html
<h1>
  <my-element></my-element> <!-- red! warning! -->
</h1>
<div>
  <my-element></my-element> <!-- no red, a-ok -->
</div>
```